# What's the best way to restrict gamemode per-world in MultiWorld?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server, minecraft-bukkit, minecraft-spigot

I have a MultiWorld server set up (Spigot 1.8 using the MultiWorld plugin) which I would like to have some worlds lock everyone into creative mode and others lock everyone into survival mode.  I've been unable to figure out how to get it to do this.  Setting the defaultmode only seems to affect your initial login.  Setting the CreativeMode flag on a world in the MutliWorld settings doesn't seem to have any effect for me.

I've tried a couple plugins that claim to force gamemode but haven't succeeded in getting them to work.  The most-closely-matched with my intended purpose seems to be GameModeChanger_Rewrite, but it seems to change your gamemode based on the settings for the world you just left instead of the world you're going to when you move between worlds.

I'd be grateful for suggestions how to set this up!  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a commandblock loop which for every world sets the gamemode

use this command

> gamemode @a X

for X you can ether fill in 0 for survival, 1 for creative, 2 for adventure, and 3 for spectator.

here is how a loop is made: you can put an lever on it to turn it on and off easely.
[image]

download testworld [here](http://www.filedropper.com/worldforjustdave)

Comment: Just a quick question, why do you have no hunger bar?

Comment: It's an old photo from minecraft beta. I found it on the interwebs so you knew what I ment

Comment: I see two cobblestone blocks with a redstone torch on both sides of each with three patches of redstone powder in between them - where do the command blocks go here?

Comment: connected to the redstone or next to a cobblestone block

Comment: Seems like a bit of a hacky way to do it, but I guess a lot of Minecraft is like that ;-)  Gets the job done anyway.  If I need to do something as an admin I have to go track the block down and disable it though.  Also have to hide it sufficiently that users are unlikely to find it.

Comment: t's the only vanilla way. In my opinion the the least hacky way. I am going to make you a world that can show you a little setup to get rid of your problems from the comment above, It's probebly to technical for you to just tell you

Comment: Check the edit under the picture for more info on how I made it

Comment: 1.9: just use a repeating command block instead of all the redstone

Answer (score 0):

This is easy, all you need to do is test for the gamemode that you don't want players using, then changing their gamemode to survival or adventure.

> /execute @a[m=1] /gamemode @a 0

This example tests for players in gamemode 1, creative mode,and switches them to gamemode 0, survival mode. All you need to do is hook it up to a clock.

Comment: There are two problems with this: 1. The command should be **if you were to use `/execute`** `/execute @a[m=1] ~ ~ ~ /gamemode 0 @a` 2. `/execute` does not need to be used here. In the `/gamemode` command you can use the `@a[m=1]` selector like so: `/gamemode 0 @a[m=1]`.